# Opening a modal from a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a project based on angular2-webpack-starter seed project and I am attempting to integrate ng-bootstrap - specifically modals.

I have a SharedModule where I import NgbModule and re-export it.  Every other module in my application imports SharedModule.

I have configured ngbModalContainer in my app.component.html as per the docs.

I now have a lazy loaded module that needs to open a modal.  When I try and call the open(...) method on the NgbModal service I am getting an error stating that it can't find the container:

> Missing modal container, add 
>   to one of your application templates.

I assume this is because the lazy loaded module is importing SharedModule and is receiving a separate instance of the NgbModal service than the root app module.

My question is - what is the correct way to configure this so NgbModal (and the rest of ng-bootstrap services/components) are available application wide, including lazy loaded modules.

Thanks!

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/784 so we can investigate.

Comment: What happens if you import `NgbModule.forRoot()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In root module(app.module.ts) imports NgbModule.forRoot()
then lazy loaded module import NgbModule

Comment: I'll mark this as correct but at the time of this question there was no forRoot method available.  I actually contributed by adding it :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "lazy load module import NgbModule" please? How do I lazy load an import (and not a route?)